# Hide show divs one by one

Tags: jquery, hide, show

```
.visible{display:block;}
.hidden{display:none;}

<div class="section-container">      
    <div id="sec_1" class="section visible">1</div> <!-- Should be visible always -->
    <div id="sec_2" class="section hidden">2</div>
    <div id="sec_3" class="section hidden">3</div>
    <div id="sec_4" class="section hidden">4</div>
    <div id="sec_5" class="section hidden">5</div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="show">Show<button>
<button type="button"  id="hide">Hide<button>

jQuery(document).ready(function (){
   jQuery('#hide').click(function(){
     //Code
   });
   jQuery('#show').click(function(){
     //Code 
   });
});
```

How to show `.section` divs one by one i.e second `.section` becomes visible on show button click and so on, but once hide button is clicked, last visible `.section` div should be hidden. But first `.section` div should never be hidden, it should be visible always.

Comment: Try using [time intervals to do it](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) loop and change the attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Attribute selector `[]` to get ID elements which ID Starts-With `^=` , and ignore the first element from the retrieved collection by using `.slice(1)`

```
$("[id^='sec_']").slice(1)
```

than play with the `:hidden` and `:visible` selectors by using the `.filter()` method in combination with `.first()` and `.last()`

```js
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  var $sec = $("[id^='sec_']").slice(1); // Get all but first 

  $('#hide').click(function(){
    $sec.filter(":visible").last().addClass("hidden");
  });
   
  $('#show').click(function(){
    $sec.filter(":hidden").first().removeClass("hidden");
  });
   
});
```

```css
/* why you want to use .visible? :) */
.hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show">SHOW</button>
<button id="hide">HIDE</button>

<div class="section-container">      
    <div id="sec_1" class="section">1</div>
    <div id="sec_2" class="section hidden">2</div>
    <div id="sec_3" class="section hidden">3</div>
    <div id="sec_4" class="section hidden">4</div>
    <div id="sec_5" class="section hidden">5</div>
</div>
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/
https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/
https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

this is an example it may helps you

https://jsfiddle.net/qss1z141/

```
$("#show").click(function(){
$("#2").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
});
$("#hide").click(function(){
$("#2").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
});
```